# Can not install Web Essentials to VS12

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-essentials

I can't seem to install WebEssentials.  I keep getting this error, even though I get the VS icon for the VSIX extension, & have updated VS12 inside the program.

```
2013-02-07 21:59:15 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
2013-02-07 21:59:15 - -------------------------------------------
2013-02-07 21:59:15 - Initializing Install...
2013-02-07 21:59:16 - Extension Details...
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -   Identifier      : 5fb7364d-2e8c-44a4-95eb-2a382e30fec7
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -   Name            : Web Essentials 2012
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -   Author          : Mads Kristensen
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -   Version         : 2.4.5
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -   Description     : Adds many useful features to Visual Studio for web developers.
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -   Locale          : en-US
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -   MoreInfoURL     : http://vswebessentials.com/changelog
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -   InstalledByMSI  : False
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : 4.5
2013-02-07 21:59:16 - 
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -   Supported Products : 
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -           Version : 11.0
2013-02-07 21:59:16 - 
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -   References      : 
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -       -------------------------------------------------------
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF.11.0
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -       Name         : Visual Studio MPF 11.0
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -       Version      : 11.0
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -       MoreInfoURL  : 
2013-02-07 21:59:16 -       Nested       : No
2013-02-07 21:59:16 - 
2013-02-07 21:59:16 - 
2013-02-07 21:59:16 - Searching for applicable products...
2013-02-07 21:59:16 - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web
2013-02-07 21:59:16 - Found installed product - Global Location
2013-02-07 21:59:16 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

The only curveball I can think of is that I did not use the custom folder for installing VS12.  TIA

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unfortunately VS Web Express doesn't allow 3rd party extensions to be installed. Therefore it only works in VS Pro, Premium and Ultimate

Comment: Ah, thanks!
I couldn't find that answer anywhere, including VS Web Express' error messages.  Web Essentials is the only reason why I installed Visual Studio...

Comment: boo, boo MS.  I love vs express, but seriously, do i really want to spend $700+ to have an ide where i can do coffeescript.  It really sends a message to developers to use another ide

Comment: but, but .. Web Essentials are essential for TypeScript! Where do I go from here?

Comment: @Anton does your company earn money with making gifts :)?